# XPath to select nodes in different namespaces

Tags: xml, xpath, jxpath

**I need some help with coming up with a proper XPath expression to extract values out of the XML.**

I can get the values using jaxb however I need xpath because I have a decision table kind of mapping rules that I want to externalise, which if I use jaxb will result in lot of nested if/else statements that I want to avoid and hence the need for xpath approach.

I have an xml file that is constructed off at least 4 schemas. I mean the root schema has an element at a particular point that says xs:any and at this location a xml based off a different schema is injected and this in turn has a similar xs:any where another xml is injected to build the final/actual xml that i work with.

This is the actual XML structure that I'm dealing with (I have intentionally modified the values).**The two Document nodes in the xml below are based off different schemas**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<env:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:env="CDTS-SUBMIT">
  <env:Body>
    <cdtPrefix>
      <cdtprVersion>01</cdtprVersion>
      <cdtprOperation>SUBMIT</cdtprOperation>
      <cdtprFunction>GCAMS1O</cdtprFunction>
      <cdtprDirectionFlag>O</cdtprDirectionFlag>
    </cdtPrefix>
    <cdtDataDescription>
      <cdtddVersion>01</cdtddVersion>
      <cdtddFirmId>ABC</cdtddFirmId>
      <cdtddBusinessDataFormat>GCAMS1O-XML</cdtddBusinessDataFormat>
      <cdtddReferenceNum>123</cdtddReferenceNum>
      <cdtddTrackingNum>123</cdtddTrackingNum>
      <cdtddDestination>AQ</cdtddDestination>
      <cdtddSeqNum>0000000</cdtddSeqNum>
      <cdtddCycleNum>00</cdtddCycleNum>
      <cdtddBusinessDate>00000000</cdtddBusinessDate>
    </cdtDataDescription>
    <cdtBusinessData>
      <AppHdr xmlns="urn:iso:std:iso:20022:tech:xsd:head.001.001.01" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <Fr>
          <FIId>
            <FinInstnId>
              <BICFI>ABC</BICFI>
            </FinInstnId>
          </FIId>
        </Fr>
        <To>
          <FIId>
            <FinInstnId>
              <BICFI>ABC   </BICFI>
            </FinInstnId>
          </FIId>
        </To>
        <BizMsgIdr>ABC</BizMsgIdr>
        <MsgDefIdr>seev.031.002.05</MsgDefIdr>
        <BizSvc>CSD</BizSvc>
        <CreDt>9999-99-99T00:02:17Z</CreDt>
      </AppHdr>
      <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:seev.031.002.05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <CorpActnNtfctn>
          <NtfctnGnlInf>
            <NtfctnTp>REPL</NtfctnTp>
            <PrcgSts>
              <Cd>
                <EvtCmpltnsSts>COMP</EvtCmpltnsSts>
                <EvtConfSts>CONF</EvtConfSts>
              </Cd>
            </PrcgSts>
          </NtfctnGnlInf>
          <PrvsNtfctnId>
            <Id>00000000</Id>
          </PrvsNtfctnId>
          <EvtsLkg>
            <EvtId>
              <LkdOffclCorpActnEvtId>US8</LkdOffclCorpActnEvtId>
            </EvtId>
            <LkgTp>
              <Cd>INFO</Cd>
            </LkgTp>
          </EvtsLkg>
          <CorpActnGnlInf>
            <CorpActnEvtId>000</CorpActnEvtId>
            <OffclCorpActnEvtId>US7</OffclCorpActnEvtId>
            <EvtPrcgTp>
              <Cd>DISN</Cd>
            </EvtPrcgTp>
            <EvtTp>
              <Cd>INTR</Cd>
            </EvtTp>
            <MndtryVlntryEvtTp>
              <Cd>CHOS</Cd>
            </MndtryVlntryEvtTp>
            <UndrlygScty>
              <FinInstrmId>
                <OthrId>
                  <Id>J54675AA1</Id>
                  <Tp>
                    <Cd>CUSP</Cd>
                  </Tp>
                </OthrId>
                <Desc>JASDFKASDFADSFAFADSF</Desc>
              </FinInstrmId>
              <ClssfctnTp>
                <ClssfctnFinInstrm>DBXXXX</ClssfctnFinInstrm>
              </ClssfctnTp>
            </UndrlygScty>
          </CorpActnGnlInf>
          <AcctDtls>
            <ForAllAccts>
              <IdCd>GENR</IdCd>
            </ForAllAccts>
          </AcctDtls>
          <CorpActnDtls>
            <DtDtls>
              <RcrdDt>
                <Dt>
                  <Dt>0000-04-03</Dt>
                </Dt>
              </RcrdDt>
            </DtDtls>
            <RateAndAmtDtls>
              <Intrst>
                <Rate>0</Rate>
              </Intrst>
            </RateAndAmtDtls>
            <IntrstAcrdNbOfDays>0</IntrstAcrdNbOfDays>
          </CorpActnDtls>
          <CorpActnOptnDtls>
            <OptnNb>001</OptnNb>
            <OptnTp>
              <Cd>CASH</Cd>
            </OptnTp>
            <DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
              <DfltOptnInd>true</DfltOptnInd>
            </DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
            <DtDtls>
              <RspnDdln>
                <Dt>
                  <DtTm>0000-04-10T20:00:00-04:00</DtTm>
                </Dt>
              </RspnDdln>
            </DtDtls>
            <PrdDtls>
              <ActnPrd>
                <Prd>
                  <StartDt>
                    <Dt>
                      <DtTm>0000-04-06T00:00:00-04:00</DtTm>
                    </Dt>
                  </StartDt>
                  <EndDt>
                    <NotSpcfdDt>UKWN</NotSpcfdDt>
                  </EndDt>
                </Prd>
              </ActnPrd>
            </PrdDtls>
            <CshMvmntDtls>
              <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
              <IncmTp>
                <Id>0004</Id>
                <Issr>IRSX</Issr>
              </IncmTp>
              <DtDtls>
                <PmtDt>
                  <Dt>
                    <Dt>0000-04-18</Dt>
                  </Dt>
                </PmtDt>
              </DtDtls>
              <RateAndAmtDtls>
                <IntrstRateUsdForPmt>
                  <RateTpAndAmtAndRateSts>
                    <RateTp>
                      <Cd>SCHD</Cd>
                    </RateTp>
                    <Amt Ccy="USD">21.17125</Amt>
                  </RateTpAndAmtAndRateSts>
                </IntrstRateUsdForPmt>
                <WhldgOfLclTax>
                  <Rate>15.315</Rate>
                </WhldgOfLclTax>
              </RateAndAmtDtls>
            </CshMvmntDtls>
          </CorpActnOptnDtls>
          <CorpActnOptnDtls>
            <OptnNb>002</OptnNb>
            <OptnTp>
              <Cd>CASH</Cd>
            </OptnTp>
            <OptnFeatrs>
              <Cd>ASVO</Cd>
            </OptnFeatrs>
            <DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
              <DfltOptnInd>false</DfltOptnInd>
            </DfltPrcgOrStgInstr>
            <DtDtls>
              <RspnDdln>
                <Dt>
                  <DtTm>0000-04-10T20:00:00-04:00</DtTm>
                </Dt>
              </RspnDdln>
            </DtDtls>
            <PrdDtls>
              <ActnPrd>
                <Prd>
                  <StartDt>
                    <Dt>
                      <DtTm>0000-04-06T00:00:00-04:00</DtTm>
                    </Dt>
                  </StartDt>
                  <EndDt>
                    <NotSpcfdDt>UKWN</NotSpcfdDt>
                  </EndDt>
                </Prd>
              </ActnPrd>
            </PrdDtls>
            <CshMvmntDtls>
              <CdtDbtInd>CRDT</CdtDbtInd>
              <IncmTp>
                <Id>0004</Id>
                <Issr>IRSX</Issr>
              </IncmTp>
              <DtDtls>
                <PmtDt>
                  <Dt>
                    <Dt>0000-04-18</Dt>
                  </Dt>
                </PmtDt>
              </DtDtls>
              <RateAndAmtDtls>
                <IntrstRateUsdForPmt>
                  <RateTpAndAmtAndRateSts>
                    <RateTp>
                      <Cd>SCHD</Cd>
                    </RateTp>
                    <Amt Ccy="USD">25</Amt>
                  </RateTpAndAmtAndRateSts>
                </IntrstRateUsdForPmt>
                <WhldgOfLclTax>
                  <Rate>0</Rate>
                </WhldgOfLclTax>
              </RateAndAmtDtls>
            </CshMvmntDtls>
          </CorpActnOptnDtls>
          <AddtlInf>
            <AddtlTxt>
              <UpdDt>0000-04-04</UpdDt>
              <AddtlInf> adfafadfasdfasdfasdfsdafadfdsafdf</AddtlInf>
            </AddtlTxt>
          </AddtlInf>
          <Regar>
            <NmAndAdr>
              <Nm>Not Available</Nm>
            </NmAndAdr>
          </Regar>
          <SplmtryData>
            <Envlp>
              <Document xmlns="urn:swift:xsd:supl.001.001.05" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <DTCCCANOCSDDataSD1>
                  <NtfctnGnlInf>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/NtfctnGnlInf</PlcAndNm>
                    <CretDtAndTm>0000-04-24T11:34:09</CretDtAndTm>
                    <UpdDtAndTm>0000-04-24T20:02:16</UpdDtAndTm>
                  </NtfctnGnlInf>
                  <CorpActnGnlInf>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnGnlInf</PlcAndNm>
                    <EDSMsggElgbltyFlg>true</EDSMsggElgbltyFlg>
                    <DTCFCPElctnFlg>false</DTCFCPElctnFlg>
                    <AsstSvcrPrcgFlg>true</AsstSvcrPrcgFlg>
                  </CorpActnGnlInf>
                  <UndrlygScty>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnGnlInf/UndrlygScty</PlcAndNm>
                    <CtryOfListg>DE</CtryOfListg>
                    <IncmSrcCtry>JP</IncmSrcCtry>
                    <DTCAsstClss>CRPB</DTCAsstClss>
                    <DTCAsstTp>S500</DTCAsstTp>
                  </UndrlygScty>
                  <CorpActnDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnDtls</PlcAndNm>
                    <CutOffDays>0</CutOffDays>
                    <EDSMsggCtryCd>JP</EDSMsggCtryCd>
                    <RDPRefNb>yyyyyyJ54675xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RDPRefNb>
                  </CorpActnDtls>
                  <CorpActnDtDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnDtls/DtDtls</PlcAndNm>
                    <DTCPosCaptrDt>0000-04-03</DTCPosCaptrDt>
                  </CorpActnDtDtls>
                  <OptnDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnOptnDtls[1]</PlcAndNm>
                    <XtndedOptnFeatrs>FORU</XtndedOptnFeatrs>
                    <DfltOptnFlg>true</DfltOptnFlg>
                    <RDPRefNb>yyyyyyJ54675xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RDPRefNb>
                  </OptnDtls>
                  <OptnDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnOptnDtls[2]</PlcAndNm>
                    <XtndedOptnFeatrs>FORX</XtndedOptnFeatrs>
                    <RDPRefNb>yyyyyyJ54675xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RDPRefNb>
                  </OptnDtls>
                  <CshMvmntDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnOptnDtls[1]/CshMvmntDtls[1]</PlcAndNm>
                    <DTCPayMtd>1</DTCPayMtd>
                    <DTCPayOrdr>0</DTCPayOrdr>
                    <NRATaxRptblFlg>false</NRATaxRptblFlg>
                    <DclrdGrssRate>
                      <AmtPricPerFinInstrmQty>
                        <AmtPricTp>ACTU</AmtPricTp>
                        <PricVal Ccy="USD">25</PricVal>
                        <FinInstrmQty>
                          <FaceAmt>1000</FaceAmt>
                        </FinInstrmQty>
                      </AmtPricPerFinInstrmQty>
                    </DclrdGrssRate>
                    <RDPRefNb>yyyyyyJ54675xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RDPRefNb>
                  </CshMvmntDtls>
                  <CshMvmntDtls>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnOptnDtls[2]/CshMvmntDtls[1]</PlcAndNm>
                    <DTCPayMtd>1</DTCPayMtd>
                    <DTCPayOrdr>0</DTCPayOrdr>
                    <NRATaxRptblFlg>false</NRATaxRptblFlg>
                    <RDPRefNb>yyyyyyJ54675xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx</RDPRefNb>
                  </CshMvmntDtls>
                  <Agt>
                    <PlcAndNm>/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/Regar/NmAndAdr</PlcAndNm>
                    <AgtId>00009910</AgtId>
                  </Agt>
                </DTCCCANOCSDDataSD1>
              </Document>
            </Envlp>
          </SplmtryData>
        </CorpActnNtfctn>
      </Document>
    </cdtBusinessData>
  </env:Body>
</env:Envelope>
```

**I have no problems extracting the first few elements
like /env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData**

**the cdtBusinessData is the element in the main schema that takes a xs:any**
.The schema snippet is as follows

```
                <xs:element name="cdtBusinessData" form="unqualified">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:sequence>
                            <xs:any minOccurs="0"/>
                        </xs:sequence>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
```

Precisely from this point on my xpath queries don't work the way I expect them to.

i.e **when I try /env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/Document then it doesn't identify it to be a proper path on jxpath**.
On different tools that provide a xpath(like xpather/firepath/XpathBuilder) for a selected node I get different values,none of which are accepted by xpath.

Could you please help me in understanding how I can go about extracting values from the two embedded  nodes in the above xml.

I have struggled with this for quite sometime now and finally reaching out for help here.
Would appreciate if you can help me to correct this path
**//env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/*Document***

---

### UPDATE

> This is what I came up with based on your suggestions.I'm using
>   jxpath
>    1.3. What am I doing wrong here ? I have comments inline next to the sysouts to indicate what I get

```
package com.testbed;

import java.io.ByteArrayInputStream;

import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder;
import javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilderFactory;

import org.apache.commons.jxpath.JXPathContext;

import com.xyz.ib.pb.dtcc.util.FileUtils;

public class TestJXPathApproach {

    public static void main(String a[]) throws Exception {              
        String xmlMsg = FileUtils.readFileContents("C:\\dtcc-stuff\\SR\\1.xml");
        //xmlMsg = StringUtils.remove(xmlMsg, "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?>");
        TestJXPathApproach myTest = new TestJXPathApproach();
        myTest.testJxPathExpressions(xmlMsg);
    }

    private void testJxPathExpressions(String xmlMsg) {
        org.w3c.dom.Document doc = null;
        try {
            DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
            ByteArrayInputStream bais = new ByteArrayInputStream(xmlMsg.getBytes("UTF8"));
            doc = builder.parse(bais);
            bais.close();
            JXPathContext context = JXPathContext.newContext(doc);
            context.setLenient(true);
            context.registerNamespace("d", "urn:swift:xsd:seev.031.002.05");
            context.registerNamespace("dd", "urn:swift:xsd:supl.001.001.05");


            String cdtddTrackingNumVal = (String)context.getValue("/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtDataDescription/cdtddTrackingNum");
            System.out.println("cdtddTrackingNumVal : "+cdtddTrackingNumVal); // prints the value correctly


            String cdVal = (String)context.getValue("/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/d:Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnGnlInf/EvtTp/Cd");
            System.out.println("cdVal : "+cdVal);// prints null with namespace mappping specified

            cdVal = (String)context.getValue("/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnGnlInf/EvtTp/Cd");
            System.out.println("cdVal : "+cdVal);// prints null with no namespace mapping 

            cdVal = (String)context.getValue("/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/*:Document/CorpActnNtfctn/CorpActnGnlInf/EvtTp/Cd");
            System.out.println("cdVal : "+cdVal);// prints null with wildcard namespace mapping 

            Object nodeObj  = context.selectSingleNode("/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/d:Document/CorpActnNtfctn");
            System.out.println("nodeObj : "+nodeObj);// prints null


        }catch(Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: I assume you want this to work with `Document` allowed to be in **any** namespace?

Comment: From Amit K: _Do you have the schema for xml you have put in your question?_

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a *namespace wildcard* for Document, if you want to be able to select either one:

```
/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/*:Document
```

...or, to get both documents in one query:

```
//*:Document
```

See a full XQuery document which you can run yourself to see this working at https://gist.github.com/charles-dyfis-net/983d4054f4f9424a1698

---

Versions of the above compatible with XPath 1.0 ([many thanks to @kjhughes](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31346412/14122)):

```
/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/*[local-name()='Document']
```

...or...

```
//*[local-name() = 'Document']
```

Answer (score 2):

If you've [registered](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-jxpath/apidocs/org/apache/commons/jxpath/JXPathContext.html#registerNamespace(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) the following namespace prefixes in JXPath,

```
JXPathContext.registerNamespace("sw", "urn:swift:xsd:seev.031.002.05")
JXPathContext.registerNamespace("env", "CDTS-SUBMIT")
```

then the following XPath,

```
/env:Envelope/env:Body/cdtBusinessData/sw:Document
```

will select the `Document` element in the `urn:swift:xsd:seev.031.002.05` namespace successfully.

### Update

If you want to select a `Document` element in a different namespace, register a prefix for the new namespace similarly and use it instead in your XPath.

**Using registered namespace prefixes is generally prefered practice**, but if you want to disregard the namespaces, in **XPath 2.0** you can use the `*:Document` technique [shown by Charles Duffy](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31346534/290085).

In **XPath 1.0**, the `*:` technique won't work but instead you can test against element's local name:

```
//*[local-name() = 'Document']
```

will select all `Document` elements regardless of namespace (and regardless of heritage).

Comment: Thx v much for the prompt response but I'm afraid I'm still not there.I have updated the original question with a test class that I came up with based on suggestions by you both.I still get a null instead of the desired value.Could you please let me know where I'm going wrong.

Comment: For your last XPath trial, realize that `CorpActnNtfctn` is also in the default namespace of its ancestor and thus also must be preceded by a `d:` namespace prefix.  Lack of this understanding is also behind a number of the other example failures.  The one that uses `*:` cannot work unless the XPath processor supports XPath 2.0.

Comment: Do you mind if I incorporate the `local-name()` approach into my answer?

Comment: @CharlesDuffy: Feel free to incorporate material from this or any of my answers.  Happy to help and flattered to be asked.  Thank you.